# URI not working and just adding to URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I'm trying to get my head around custom URIs. I would like my `view_county` to have the URL:

http://localhost/chipadvisor2/controller_ca/all_county/1

and my `view_all` to have the URL:

http://localhost/chipadvisor2/controller_ca/all_chippers

If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it. The link works for `view_county` but when I click on the `view_all` link it shows:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "error": "Unknown method"
}
```

and if I click into `view_county` first then the `view_all` link it just keeps adding `controller_ca/all_chippers` to the URL and doing nothing. Any ideas why?

### model_ca

```
<?php
class Model_ca extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_chipper() {
        $query = $this->db->get('chipper_reviews');
        return $query->result();
    }

    function get_county($id) {
        $this->db->where('location', 'Westmeath');
        $query = $this->db->get('chipper_reviews');
        return $query->result();
    }

}
?>
```

### controller_ca

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class Controller_ca extends REST_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('model_ca');
    }

    public function index_get() {  
        $this->all_chipper_get();
    }

    public function all_chipper_get() {
        $data['chipper'] = $this->model_ca->get_chipper();
        $this->load->view('view_all', $data);
    }    

    public function all_county_get() {
        $id = $this->uri->rsegment(3);
        $data['location'] = $this->model_ca->get_county('location',$id);
        $this->load->view('view_county', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

### view_county

and

### view_all

```
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="controller_ca/all_chippers">View All Chippers</a>
            <br/>
            <a href="controller_ca/all_county/1">View County</a>

            <?php echo "<br/><br/>";
            foreach ($chipper as $chipperdata) {
                echo "<b>Name: </b>".$chipperdata->name." "."<br/>"."<b>County: </b>".$chipperdata->location." "."<br/>"."<b>Description: </b>".$chipperdata->description." "."<br/>"."<br/>";
            } ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have added this to the route.php file also but don't know how to put it into effect or how to add the value 'westmeath' to the end. Ideally I would like to pass it as a variable rather than hardcoding it:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Controller_ca';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = false;

$route['all_chipper'] = 'controller_ca/all_chippers';

$route['all_county'] = 'controller_ca/all_county/$1';
```

Comment: I guess problem is in you routing. You have not mentioned controller name before function name in routing rule like `$route['controller_ca/all_county'] = 'controller_ca/all_county/$1';` and `$route['controller_ca/all_chipper'] = 'controller_ca/all_chippers';`...

Comment: I tried that and it stops both links from working.

Comment: One thing i don't understand, why 2nd link `<a>` has `controller` instead of `controller_ca`? Even this is in the routing as well.

Comment: Whoops, that is changed now but still the same issue with it just adding `controller_ca/all_chippers` and `controller_ca/all_county/1` to my URL every time I click a link rather than it simply clicking over and back.

Comment: I am not getting you. What is the error now?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue:

> and if I click into view_county first then the view_all link it just
>   keeps adding controller_ca/all_chippers to the URL and doing nothing.
>   Any ideas why?

Please add `base_url()` at the starting of URL in anchor tag. It will resolve the `append` issue in URL. Example:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/controller_ca/all_chippers">View All Chippers</a>
<br/>
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/controller_ca/all_county/1">View County</a>
```

Also, change your routing as:

```
$route['controller_ca/all_county'] = 'controller_ca/all_county/$1';
$route['controller_ca/all_chipper'] = 'controller_ca/all_chippers';
```

Comment: Hmm... Now this is bringing me to a 404 page?

Comment: What's happening is that it's not adding my base url which is weird right? It's just changing the url to localhost/controller_ca/all_county/$1 as opposed to localhost/folder/controller_ca/all_county/$1

Comment: Have you defined Base path in `config.php`?

Comment: I hadn't because I have the rewrite mod on, but when I did it brought me to this message: ` {"status":false,"error":"Unknown method"}`

Comment: Can you please tell what exactly you have defined in `base_url` line from config file?

Comment: in my `config.php` file I have: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myfoldername/';` My routing is as stated in my question and I am calling the URI with `<a href="<?php base_url(); ?>/controller_ca/all_chippers">View All Chippers</a>`

Comment: So `all_chippers` isn't working but `all_county` is. I can't make sense of it!?

Answer (score 0):

Try to give controller method name same as url. Change `all_chipper_get()` to `all_chipper()`. Same for other method and check.

Comment: No still not working. _get is there because I am using RESTful.